# Schedule a function to run each day in the backend [LARAVEL]

Tags: mysql, laravel

Each day at 00:00 I would like to execute a function that performs an update operation on certain records in the mysql database (It will check if any machines have passed the allowed detection interval).
I would like to know the best way to do this in Laravel (v9.0)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at cron (jobs). And the Laravel scheduler

Comment: If all actions which must be performed by this function are SQL queries executions then MySQL's built-in Event Scheduler usage is the most reasonable solution. Laravel code can be used for event procedure creation - this creation must be performed only once (but I recommend you to do this via CLI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For laravel :

goto app->console->kernel.php

then, Write all the function/commands inside schedule functions.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        //Do Something here!!
    })->daily();
}
```

or if you want to run some artisan function say queue:work:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    //Start queue works every minutes
    $schedule->command('queue:work --stop-when-empty')->everyMinute();

}
```

If you want to run scheduler at specified time use :

`->dailyAt('13:00')`  instead of `->daily()`

You will need to run this command in console:

`php artisan schedule:run`

For reference:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#defining-schedules